# Perl: How to make 64 bit perl compiler requirement mandatory to run the program

Tags: perl

I'm interested to know if there is a way to force a program to execute only in a x64 bit perl compiler. If the program runs in a 32 bit compiler, it should throw an error and exit.
Something similar to `require 5.10.0`.
I have a program that has a lot of 64 bit integer processing to do. All of them are in string format and `hex "0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"` does not get processed by a 32 bit compiler (Heard somewhere only upto 53bits are supported). I do know that we can use `Math::BigInt`, but I'm looking to remove use of libraries since the script will be running in other systems that may not have this library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite all the talk about compilers, it sounds like you actually want to check that Perl's integers are (at least) 64 bits in size. For that, you could use the following:

```
use Config qw( %Config );

BEGIN { die("64-bit ints required.\n") if $Config{ivsize} < 8; }
```

or

```
BEGIN { die("64-bit ints required.\n") if length(pack('j', 0)) < 8; }
```

or

```
BEGIN { die("64-bit ints required.\n") if ~0 <= 0xFFFF_FFFF; }
```

I placed the check in a `BEGIN` block so you don't have any problems if you have large constants in your program.

Comment: Yup! Tested it out in a 32bit perl and it works fine. Thanks! Can you explain what's happening here?

Comment: @Arun, What don't you understand?

Comment: What does ~0 <= 0xFFFF_FFFF mean?

Comment: @Arun, Did you check [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)? `~` beforms bitwise negation, so `~0` returns `0xFFFF_FFFF` for 32-bit integers, and `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF` for 64-bit integers.

Comment: ooh... its a nice intuitive way to write code! I got confused by the underscore in the hex value ... I've never used hex values in this way before. But got the ~ operation. Thanks again!

Comment: You know how commas are often used in large numbers for readability (e.g. 1,234,567)? Perl allows `_` to be used in numeric literals for the same reason.

Comment: yeah ... got it now. :)